# My timer gets jammed when I try to change colour in the last 30 seconds

Tags: c#, timer

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mins = timeleft / 60;
        secs = timeleft % 60;

        if (secs > 0)
        {
            timeleft = timeleft - 1;
            secs = secs - 1;
            timerlbl.Text = "Time Left:- " + mins + ":" + secs;
        }

        if ((secs == 0) && (mins > 0))
        {
            timeleft = timeleft - 1;
            mins = mins - 1;
            secs = 59;
            timerlbl.Text = "Time Left:- " + mins + ":" + secs;
        }

        if ((secs == 0) && (mins == 0))
        {
            timerlbl.Text = "Time Left:- " + mins + ":" + secs;
            MessageBox.Show("times up");
            timer.Stop();
        }

        while((secs < 30) && (mins == 0))
        {
            timerlbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }


    }
```

** the timer was working fine until i try to change the colour??? why does it get stuck at 30 seconds??? I usually use system drawing to change label colours and it works fine**

Comment: Your code is `while((secs < 30) && (mins == 0))`, so your condition will keep the loop running when this is true. Clearly if you're running in this loop forever, other execution on the same thread can't take place. I'm not really sure why this isn't another `if` statement?

Comment: @John Looks to my like a typo

Comment: I'd replace `while((secs < 30) && (mins == 0))` with `if(timeleft < 30)` which both solves the freeze problem due to `while` and simplifies the condition

Comment: Unrelated: I'm not sure either to why you'd change the value for both `secs` and `mins` as they both refresh with the first two lines of your tick method (one `if(timeleft > 0) timeleft--;` at the beginning should do the job instead of checking so many conditions)

Comment: An additional note: a timer configured to tick once a second will actually tick less, around once every 1.1 or 1.2 seconds. Do not use the number of timer ticks to calculate the passage of time! Use a stopwatch if you want to count down a certain number of seconds, or use DateTime if you want to count down to a particular wall-clock time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify A LOT with just:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timeleft = timeleft - 1;
    mins = timeleft / 60;
    secs = timeleft % 60;
    timerlbl.Text = "Time Left:- " + mins + ":" + secs;

    if (timeleft < 30)
    {
        timerlbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    if (timeleft == 0)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("times up");
    }
}
```

Comment: `timerlbl.Text = "Time Left:- " + mins + ":" + secs;` could go outside the `if/else` so you only write it once too (as there should be no way it `timeleft` goes negative) - anyway that's quite close to what I'd written (+1)

Comment: @Rafalon, true.  Let's simplify it even more.

Comment: I guess that for the downvoter to remove his vote you'd have to add that OP's `while` loop was responsible for the jam so it actually answers the question instead of giving a simpler & cleaner code on a silver plate (but that's just a guess) - Something like "*`secs` and `mins` are not changing inside the loop so it's an infinite loop (because the condition `secs < 30 && mins == 0` never becomes false) which results in a jam*"